# How to set friendlyName for an Azure Data Catalog Asset via REST API?

Tags: azure-data-catalog

I am registering assets to Azure Data Catalog via REST API. I could register my assets without any problem. When I want to add a "friendyName" to my assets, I get an error. I am using the exact syntax that is shown [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/data-catalog-dotnet-excel-register-data-assets/blob/master/AdHocContainerSample.json#L27). Here is the json that I am sending:

```
"annotations": {
    "schema": {
        "properties": {
            "fromSourceSystem": false, 
            "columns": [{"name": "com.xxx.xx.claim ", "type": " VARCHAR"}, {"name": "com.xx.xx.requirement ", "type": " VARCHAR"}]
        }
    },
    "tableDataProfiles": [{"properties": {"dataModifiedTime": "2020-05-12 17:26:37.706521", "schemaModifiedTime": "2020-05-12 17:26:37.706537", "fromSourceSystem": false, "key": "tableDataProfiles"}}], 
    "columnsDataProfiles": [{"properties": {"columns": [{"columnName": "com.xx.xx.claim ", "type": " VARCHAR"}, {"columnName": "com.xx.xx.requirement ", "type": " VARCHAR"},], 
    "tags": [{"properties": {"tag": "uploadedByScript", "key": "tag", "fromSourceSystem": false}}],
    "experts": [{"properties": {"expert": {"upn": "Berkan@xx.de"}, "fromSourceSystem": false, "key": "expert"}}],
    "friendlyName": {"properties": {"friendlyName": "Requirements", "fromSourceSystem": false}}
}
```

I have cut the irrelevant parts of the json to make it readible. Notice "friendlyName" annotation is under "annotations" as described in the sample code. Can someone point out, what is wrong with my json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the syntax was correct. I have realized, some of my input strings are either null or non-trimmed. That was the problem. I confirm the syntax above is correct.